# Install RStudio on AWS EC2 instance

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rstudio, putty

I managed to create an *EC2* instance *Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1* (randomly chosen) on *Amazon Web Services* (*AWS*).
I can send and receive files from my local desktop to *AWS* properly.

Now I would like to install *R* (*RStudio Server*) on *AWS*.
When searching for an answer, I found the script below that is to be written into *Putty*:

```
# install R base
$ sudo yum install r-base

#install RStudio-Server 1.1.442
$ sudo yum install gdebi-core
$ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-1.1.442-amd64.deb
$ sudo gdebi rstudio-server-1.1.442-amd64.deb

#add user(s)
useradd username
echo username:password | passwordtest
```

But the answer I get each time is: "No package r-base available" or also "No package gdebi-core available".

Are they some prerequisite steps that I am missing?
Thanks.
M

Comment: there is also a powerful AMI that includes Rstudio (http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Amazon Linux AMI 2017.09.1` is based on Centos 6 and the step you got is for Ubuntu(gdebi is an Ubuntu installer), Here are the steps from the [official documentation.](https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/)

```
$ sudo yum install R
$ wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.442-x86_64.rpm
$ sudo yum install rstudio-server-rhel-1.1.442-x86_64.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you Sudharsan !! Worked just fine !